# Why do the Oracle hibernate dialects produce invalid schemas?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, hibernate

In my project, I need to support multiple databases from multiple vendors (notably, Oracle, MSSQL and MySQL).

I have a class which creates `.sql` files for each DB type based on my annotated hibernate model classes.

I have a class `MyEntity.java` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Date timestamp;
    private String data;

    public MyEntity() {
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_table_seq", sequenceName = "my_table_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_table_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "timestamp", nullable = false)
    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return this.timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    @Column(name = "data", length = 65535)
    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

This class was produced by `hbm2java` using reverse engineering from a MySQL database. The "data" column was a `TEXT` and the "timestamp" column was a `TIMESTAMP`.

When I use the `SchemaExporter` class to generate SQL for other DB types (like oracle for example) it produces invalid plsql. This class (using the `Oracle10gDialect` produces oracle sql like this:

```
create table my_table (
    id integer not null,
    data varchar(65535),
    timestamp datetime not null
);
```

`varchar(65535)` is invalid because varchars can't be that long, and `datetime` is apparently not a real datatype.

When using the MySQL dialect, it correctly defines "data" as a `MEDIUMTEXT` type.

Why does it generate invalid oracle SQL? Is there some way I can hint to hibernate that it should use a text type? Or am I going to have to extend the oracle dialect to fix up all the data types?

**Note**: I'm using oracle 11.2.0.2.v7 and hibernate 4.2.8.FINAL
**Another Note**: Similar invalid results are produced for MSSQL (varchar(65535) is invalid).
**Disclaimer**: I'm new to Oracle

Comment: Well, you did define your "data" column to have a max length of 65535. FYI, oracle VARCHAR2 has a max size of 4000 bytes. If you need bigger, then you need to declare as a CLOB. The 32K size you mention for VARCHAR2 is the limit for PL/SQL, not SQL. Yes, it is confusing. Here is link to data type limits - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm ALso, "timestamp" is a reserved word in Oracle as a datatype. Good luck trying to write a database-neutral app.  You will need it.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the limits, I just wondered why hibernate does not. Also I don't understand why it created "timestamp" as a type of "datetime" which is not a valid datatype for oracle...

Comment: Weird - this would be a valid create for sqlserver. I take it you were expecting types of CLOB and DATE in Oracle. Might be worth looking at open issues with hibernate